# why mingw32 and tdm-gcc64 behave differently using external gcc

Tags: haskell, gcc, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

I am trying to `cabal install` a component of wxHaskell (Haskell platform 2013.2 against wxWidgets 3.0).
I was able to compile the git version with 32 bit mingw from mingw.org. But in the end, the installed wx cannot function correct, and running a minimal example gives runtime exceptions in wxc.dll. So I try to compile the same thing under TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64bit, since the wxWidgets people provide their binary in the form of TDM-GCC compiled binaries.

But I immediately run into compilation errors with TDM-GCC, telling me

error: 'strnlen' was not declared in this scope

What surprises me is that even though both mingw32 and TDM-gcc uses the same external gcc from Haskell Platform `c:\HaskellPlatform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe`, one would give an error while the other compiles fine.

The first file causing problem is `src\cpp\eljaccelerator.cpp`. It compiles OK under mingw32:

```
...
c:\HaskellPlatform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-
memory-overheads -Isrc/include -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0 -IC:/Min
GW/msys/1.0/local/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-3.0 -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -D_LAR
GEFILE_SOURCE=unknown -DwxcREFUSE_MEDIACTRL -DBUILD_DLL -c src\cpp\eljaccelerato
r.cpp -o dist\build\src/cpp/eljaccelerator.o
```

but gives an error under TDM-gcc:

```
Building wxc
c:\HaskellPlatform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-
memory-overheads -Isrc/include -IC:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0 -IC:/min
gw/msys/1.0/local/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-3.0 -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -D_FIL
E_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DwxcREFUSE_MEDIACTRL -DBUILD_DLL -c src\cpp\eljaccelerator.cpp
 -o dist\build\src/cpp/eljaccelerator.o
In file included from C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/crt.h:19:0,
                 from C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/string.h:4305,
                 from C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/memory.h:15,
                 from C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/object.h:19,
                 from C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wx.h:15,
                 from src/include/wrapper.h:20,
                 from src\cpp\eljaccelerator.cpp:1:
C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen
(const char*, size_t)':
C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h:173:92: error: 'strnlen' was n
ot declared in this scope
C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen
(const wchar_t*, size_t)':
C:/mingw/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h:187:95: error: 'wcsnlen' was n
ot declared in this scope
Failed to install wxc-0.90.1.1
```

I was wondering if anyone has any similar experience. Any idea what went wrong and how to fix compilation for TDM-GCC? I tried adding `#include <cstring>` to `wxcrt.h` but it doesn't change anything.

FYI, I have compiled wxWidgets 3.0.0 from source in mingw and tdm-gcc versions respectively, using

```
./configure --enable-stl && make && make install
```

I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, wxWidgets certainly does work with MinGW, the fact that only TDM binaries are provided simply means that someone volunteered to provide the latter but not the former. But all three popular versions of MinGW (the two already mentioned and MinGW-w64) do work, so there must be something wrong with the build...

However while they all work, they are certainly *different* compilers, so what do you mean that they both use the same gcc binary? It must be either a MinGW one or a TDM one, but it can't be both at once.

It's also very suspicious that the configure detects different flags to use for the large file support. Look at `config.log`, something must have gone wrong and there must be some errors in the initial stage in it.

Comment: As said in the OP and shown in the excerpt of output, `cabal` calls the internal mingw/gcc coming from Haskell platform 2013.2, regardless whether cabal is invoked from mingw32 or tdm.

Comment: There is plenty of issues associated with compiling wxWidgets from source if you do a search on internet, most of which comes from the fact that mingw has differences from standard gcc. The wxWidgets maintainers made a strong position that bugs in MinGW/gcc and platform specific issues are not their fault (correctly) and therefore not their problems. see e.g. http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15646. I found your claim that wx works for all three popular versions of MinGW work shaky at best, if your are talking about compiling from source.

Comment: wx 3.0.0 was tested with all of the compilers mentioned and did build out of the box with them. Of course, it's impossible to test _all_ version of all compilers and the ticket #15646 is about an especially broken release but it's an exception rather than a rule. Anyhow, this problem is just an obvious typo in the MinGW headers and has nothing to do with the problems you are having.

Comment: To return to your actual problem, it's clearly related to `cabal` using a different compiler (and probably CRT too) than your compiler. If you are using `cabal` you must use its compiler and its headers for building everything. You are mixing up different compilers, no surprise it doesn't work.

Comment: so now that the problem is understood, what's the solution? it's a standard procedure to build wxHaskell. `no surprise` doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything cabal, I've only used it once in my life. The only advice I can give is that you **must** ensure that the same toolset (ie compiler+CRT) is used for building everything, so that when you run configure you must use the same compiler with it (set `CXX` on its command line to point to it).

Comment: Well, the Haskell internal gcc is pretty old (4.5.2). I don't think it wise to compile wxWidgets using that version because that requires compiling everything else with the external gcc compiler, to avoid generating issues elsewhere/everywhere.  I'll just leave this post as a note for the wxHaskell/wxWidgets maintainers that such an issue exists. Maybe someone will come up a solution for average users like me. I was hoping that I missed something easily fixable.

Comment: FWIW wxWidgets should compile without problems with 4.5. It still builds with 3.4, I think...