# undefined strnlen function (wxWidgets) when a program is compiled using a different version of gcc by cabal

Tags: c++, haskell, wxwidgets, cabal

Here is my situation, I built wxWidgets 3.0 from source using TDM-GCC 4.8.1. 
Then we I use Haskell's `cabal` system to build certain packages that depends on wx (such as wxHaskell), `cabal` invokes its internal version of gcc to compile C++ programs, (in my case, `/c/HaskellPlatform/2013.2.0.0/mingw/bin/gcc`). Now the cabal/Haskell version of gcc generates a compile error on a simple program as follows:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
int main() {}
```

But the compilation is OK when compiling with TDM-GCC's gcc (or when Haskell's gcc is used on a mingw32-gcc compiled wxWidgets). So problem is that `cabal` and MinGW use different versions of gcc, and I can't replace MinGW gcc with the Haskell gcc because it is old (gcc 4.5.2 as of Haskell Platform 2013.2). Also the Haskell gcc is called `realgcc.exe`, and I am not even sure that it is compatible with any popular MinGW distribution.

-- details --

The error message from compiling the above minimal program using Haskell gcc is:

```
D:\work\wxHaskell-wxwidgets-3.0.0\wxc>c:\HaskellPlatform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gc
c.exe -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads -Isrc/include -IC:/MinGW/
msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0 -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/wx/include/msw-unico
de-3.0 -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=unknown -DwxcREFUSE_MEDIACTR
L -DBUILD_DLL -c src\cpp\apppath.cpp -o dist\build\src/cpp/apppath.o
In file included from C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/crt.h:19:0,
                 from C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/string.h:4305,
                 from C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/memory.h:15,
                 from C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/object.h:19,
                 from C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wx.h:15,
                 from src/include/wrapper.h:20,
                 from src\cpp\apppath.cpp:1:
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen
(const char*, size_t)':
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h:173:92: error: 'strnlen' was n
ot declared in this scope
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h: In function 'size_t wxStrnlen
(const wchar_t*, size_t)':
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxcrt.h:187:95: error: 'wcsnlen' was n
ot declared in this scope
```

I googled around and some suggest adding `#include <cstring>;`. I added that to the beginning of `wxcrt.h`, and that didn't solve the problem.

The thing is the same compile error for realgcc 4.5.2 wouldn't happen, if I compile wxWidgets 3.0 using mingw32 from mingw.org. (But I run into DLL access violation errors via that path).

My question is why `realgcc` recognize `strnlen` and `wcsnlen` if the source code is built with standard MinGW32, but fail when the source is compiled with TDM-GCC? And how do we hack realgcc/mingw32/tdm-gcc (or something else) to fix this error?

I known mixing different version of mingw/gcc is dangerous, but average users do not have much choice here as build systems like cabal choose their own compilers without consulting. An additional question is, is there a safe way to change the default gcc program `cabal` use without breaking cabal?

I use TDM-gcc because TDM-GCC binaries are the binaries provided by the wxWidgets maintainers, and I think this has better chance succeeding. I tried to `cabal build` wx using MinGW-w64 gcc and got runtime exceptions about `cc1plus.exe` during compilation. Counting the run-time issue said earlier about mingw32, going with TDM-GCC is probably the best shot, as I figured.

-- update --

@icktoofay

Here is what I've tried, doesn't seem to have changed gcc compiler.

$ cabal configure --ghc-option=-pgmc --ghc-option=/c/mingw/bin/gcc.exe
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring wxc-0.90.1.1...
Configuring wxc to build against wxWidgets 3.0

$ cabal build
Building wxc
c:\HaskellPlatform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-

Comment: As I wrote in reply to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392028/why-mingw32-and-tdm-gcc64-behave-differently-using-external-gcc/22394277#22394277), you really need to look at `config.log` to see what is going on.

Comment: @VZ I am not sure what you are talking about in this post as in the others about config.log. There is really not much info in either of your comments. Blindly down voting valid questions while asserting problem is always with user is ridiculous in both occasions.

Comment: As you said yourself, you have used cabal only once in your life and really don't know much about it. I don't why you assume the problem lies in how wxWidgets is built. @ickfootay's answer here is already much better than your random guesses about the user must have configured wxWidgets wrong. As you've already seen in the other question, wxWidgets was configured using standard configure command and there wasn't any issue in building wxWidgets.

Comment: @VZ. What does it have to with looking at config.log of wxWidgets if wxWidgets didn't fail in building?

Comment: Really awfully sorry for trying to help you in spite of not knowing much about `cabal`, won't happen again. Especially when you have already decided that there was nothing wrong in your configure step. Obviously you're right and the rest of the mysterious problems you are having has nothing at all to do with not building correctly.

Comment: @VZ I apologize for being over-critical about wx. I honestly do respect your work, and like wx for its purely c++ approach. I was probably spending too much time on specific issues with using specific versions of wx instead of taking a pragmatic approach (and thus get frustrated at times). I hope you understand that in some way I am a big supporter of wx. Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak as to why you're getting the error you are, but I can tell you how to change the C compiler Cabal and GHC are using. It's actually GHC that calls the C compiler, and looking in [this section of the user manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#replacing-phases), we find:

> **`-pgmc cmd`** Use `cmd` as the C compiler.

So that's how you tell GHC to use a certain C compiler. Now the question is how to get Cabal to tell GHC to use that C compiler. Fortunately, [Cabal's user manual goes into that, too](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#programs-used-for-building):

> **`--prog-options=options`** Specify additional options to the program `prog`. Any program known to Cabal can be used in place of `prog`. [ed: that means GHC, too!] […]
>   **`--prog-option=option`** […]

Either one of these will work, as the documentation shows. (Their behavior differs when arguments have spaces.) Putting this together, you might be able to get Cabal and GHC to use your preferred C compiler like this:

```
> cabal configure --ghc-option=-pgmc --ghc-option=C:\path\to\gcc.exe
> cabal build
```

If you prefer `cabal install` over `configure`/`build`, rejoice, for it works with `install`, too. If you find yourself doing this often, you may consider editing your `.cabal/config` file to change the default to use your preferred C compiler.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I tried as you suggested, but it did not change the compiler. Please see the update. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TingL: Keep in mind that GHC runs natively, not under MinGW, so you'll have to use Windows paths like `C:\path\to\gcc.exe`, not `/c/path/to/gcc.exe`.

Comment: I tried c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe (which exists), as well as `cabal build --ghc-option=-pgmc --ghc-option=C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe`, from windows command line. Somehow, the Haskell version of gcc is always picked up.

Comment: Do I need to add -cpp somewhere since the file is a cpp file?

Comment: @TingL: I'm thinking about this more now and while GHC does invoke the C compiler for some things (in which case this is sufficient), it goes to the compiler itself for some other things. Take a look at `configureCCompiler` in `Distribution.Simple.Setup`; you might be able to figure out how to change the way it discovers the C compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems to be the right direction to me.